# Why QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 return different value for $area function?

Tags: qgis, surface

I measure the area of a polygon with the QGIS Calculator: The cartesian `area($ geometry)` calculation function gives the same result for QGIS versions 2.16 and 3.4.5, but it is different with the `$area` function as shown in the image:

[image]

I don't understand why because the EPSG code and the ellipsoid are identical.

Could someone explain to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the strange area calculation in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307051/why-the-strange-area-calculation-in-qgis)

Comment: @Hornbydd This is not a duplicate of [Why the strange area calculation in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307051/why-the-strange-area-calculation-in-qgis). @fcka asks why QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 return different value for `$area` function.

Comment: The question was phrased weirdly and I didn't understand the issue at first too.My guess is that it might have something to do with the different PROJ versions between QGIS 2 and 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

QGIS Field Calculator explains why outputs of `area($ geometry)` and `$area` are different:

> `area` returns the area of a geometry polygon object. **Calculations are always
>   planimetric** in the Spatial Reference System (SRS) of this geometry,
>   and the units of the returned area will match the units for the SRS.
>   **This differs from the calculations performed by the `$area` function**,
>   which will perform **ellipsoidal calculations** based on the project's
>   ellipsoid and area unit settings.

**EDIT:** But I've noticed later that `$area` function returns different results for QGIS 2 and 3. I didn't understand that you asked that. Because the question was not clear. I tried to figure out what was the reason, and dead end. I think that it's a bug as @Stu state. I've reported this issue: [#34597](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34597)

**EDIT 2:** @ndawson's answer to the bug report:

> Trust the QGIS 3 results. They are much more accurate and reliable vs QGIS 2 which had some known bugs in area calculation.

Comment: I made myself poorly understood :

v2.16
area/10^6 :            44.1616749713555
area($geometry)/10^6   44.18969


v3.4.5
area/10^6 :            44.123126786646495
area($geometry)/10^6   44.18969

Comment: Perhaps this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @StuSmith I think it is a bug, I ve reported the issue.